# Need to put a char in a str

Tags: perl, random

I have a string `$str = 'Hello my friends';` I need to put a char `\` into every word and to get any posibble variety of this.

For example in `stdout` I want to get

```
{H\ello|He\llo|Hel\lo|Hell\o} {m\y} {f\riens|fr\iends|fri\ends.....}
```

I wrote some code, but I can't imagine what to do next:

```
my $str = 'Hello my friends';
my @ra = split / /, $str;
for(my $i=0; $i < scalar @ra; $i++)
{
    my $word = $ra[$i];
    my $num = length($word);
    my @chars = split("", $word);

    for(my $k = 0, my $l = 1; $l < $num; $k++,$l++)
    {
        print $chars[$k]."\\".$chars[$l];   
    }

}
```

Any ideas?=\

Comment: You need to escape your backslash. `"\"` is wrong. use `"\\"`, in your print statement

Comment: Edit all, but how to put a char in all possible variables?

Comment: What's the desired output for "Have a candy"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my $str = 'Hello my friends';
$str =~ s{(\S{2,})}{
    my @alts;
    for my $i (1..length($1)-1) {
        my $slashed = $1;
        substr($slashed, $i, 0, '\\');
        push @alts, $slashed;
    }
    '{' . join('|', @alts) . '}'
}eg;
```

Comment: Used s/// to preserve whitespace.

Comment: @ikegami - Could this use something like `for my $i (1..length($1)-(length $1 > 1)) { ...` and `substr($slashed, $i, 0, '\\') if length $1 > 1;` to handle one-letter words, like "I" and "a"?  Otherwise, "{}" shows for these.

Comment: @Kenosis, I'd use `if (length($1) == 1) { @alts = $1; } else { ...for... }`. But I think those should probably be left unchanged. Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the facility of `substr` that allows you to supply a fourth parameter that supplies a new string that should take the place of the substring specified. So

```
my $string = 'ABCD';
substr $string, 2, 0, '\\';
```

will result in `$string` being equal to `AB\CD`.

This program provides a solution to your problem using this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = 'Hello my friends';

my @words = split ' ', $str;
my @new_words;

foreach my $word (@words) {
  my @list
  for my $i (1 .. length($word) - 1) {
    substr my $new_word = $word, $i, 0, '\\';
    push @list, $new_word;
  }
  push @new_words, join '|', @list;
}

my $new_str = join ' ', map "{$_}", @new_words;

print $new_str;
```

**output**

```
{H\ello|He\llo|Hel\lo|Hell\o} {m\y} {f\riends|fr\iends|fri\ends|frie\nds|frien\ds|friend\s}
```